# Triggering Python and py in Task Scheduler does not work

Tags: python, windows, windows-task-scheduler

I create a task in task scheduler to open Python and run a code from a `.py` file and nothing happens.

Settings of my task:

General

Run whether user is logged in or not **TICKED**
Run with highest privileges          **TICKED**

Actions

**Program/script:** C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe
**Add arguments:** code.py (I have also tried "code.py")
**Start in** (location of my code.py): C:\Users\me\Downloads (I have also tried "C:\Users\me\Downloads")

Once I click **Run**, nothing happens. Can anyone advise please?

I was expecting that the scheduler will open Spyder, add code and run it. Not sure if this is possible or needed at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process works. It seems that my python code was not working well.

If you are in doubt just run a simple code with your Task Scheduler:

e.g.

```
import webbrowser
url = 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/'
webbrowser.open(url)
```